# Electron transparency turns white

Tags: electron, transparency

So I'm trying to program a calculator in Electron and was pretty happy as I saw, I can do transparent windows and so do rounded corners like you see here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_aVnucrbQS20RWgiRtjZYAOhUPrkwpT3

but as soon as I focus some other window the upper "rounded" corner turn to this:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u4LWUL-kdZMzAGclwpwJ3l5mP0ts8uYm

IMPORTANT: No the yellow on the pics is not gonna stay :P

Already thanking,

Elias

Comment: That might have just something to do with your operating system. Note that electron is not optimized for every operating system

Comment: I'm using Windows, and I mean the bottom corners work D:

Comment: Windows has a titlebar it's using, so maybe that is exactly what i said about electron and not being optimized for every operating system

Comment: Actually, I found the issue. The white thingy is the HTML title being displayed behind mine... Is there some way to remove it? Not sure if it is the HTML title but the content of it is being displayed in it.